# I need to convert the json output format from dictionary to array format using JAVA

Tags: java, json

I need to convert the JSON output format from:

```
"Sections" :{ "1":{ "","","" },"2":{"","",""} }" (currently available)
```

to array format:

```
"Sections": ["1":{          },"2":{    },"3":{  }] (required format)using Java
```

Comment: Your "to" format is not valid JSON. And the from format only if we leave out the "Sections": at the beginning.

Comment: Not valid JSON. Maybe you meant: `"Sections":[{content of 1},{content of 2},{content of 3}]`? That assuming that you're talking about a field and not a JSON object. In the latter case `Sections` should be deleted

Comment: Could you show Java code with an attempt of JSON converting?